# R: Tilde Symbol is showing up as an error in an equation that requires it

Tags: r, modeling, model.matrix

I have a section of code that until today was working fine. Then I tried to test my code and it broke right away.

```
X_train <- model.matrix(SALE_PRC∼., miami_train)[, -1] 
y_train <- miami_train$SALE_PRC 
X_test <- model.matrix(SALE_PRC∼., miami_test)[, -1] 
y_test <- miami_test$SALE_PRC
```

The problem is that it says that there is an unexpected tilde symbol in the code but that is exactly where it is supposed to go. Please help

Comment: You need to give us a sample of `miami_train` or `miami_test`, e.g., by including the output of `dput(head(miami_train))` in your question. `model.matrix(y ~ ., data = data.frame(x = rnorm(10L), y = rnorm(10L)))` works fine for me...

Comment: Did you copy/paste the code from somewhere? Or did you type it yourself? That tilde doesn't look like the "standard" tilde. It looks like some other unicode character. Try this `X_train <- model.matrix(SALE_PRC~., miami_train)[, -1] `

Comment: Good eye... Yes, I think their tilde is `int2Utf8(0x223C)` while the expected tilde is `int2Utf8(0x7E)`. The error thrown when I use the former is: `unexpected input in "model.matrix(y ∼"`